# How to determine Expected Value of Wait Time for a random periodic process?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability

It has been awhile since I have done any real statistics, but I am hoping the Stack Overflow Community can help. While I can't give the exact application as it is proprietary, here is an equivalent problem:

Imagine you have a bus stop near your house, but you don't know the bus schedule. Instead, you have a listing of the exact times the bus has *actually* arrived over the last year. What I want to do is calculate the following: If you randomly walk to the bus stop, what is the probability that there will be a bus in 5 mins? 10 mins? 20 mins? (I want to get a distribution).

I have already tried searching around on Google, and have found plenty examples of using a Cumulative Distribution Function... however I haven't found a single good example of how to do what I want above.

In particular, I am hoping to use the samples from the last year to create the probability distribution function I hope to use.

Does anyone have a good example of how I would go about this? (or a website that would have this data?)

Comment: You want the poisson distribution, at least as a start. Its canonical application is in modelling waiting times for arrivals. The other answers are right that you might want to look at arrival time being Poisson *conditional* on the time of day, but the Poisson is the way to go for a first stab

Answer (score 1):

I can give you few suggestions that might help:

1- To get more accurate results you need to have a conditional distribution for the time of the day (i.e. peak or off-peak) and the day of the week (week day or weekend) because the bus frequency depends on these factors

2- Try to calculate the distribution for the duration between two buses (i.e. the headway) conditioned on the above factors. The expected wait time of anyone arrive to the bus stop at random is equal to half the headway.

So the way I would go about this is to divide the data set into periods (e.g. 7-10am weekdays) and then calculate the headway for this period and this will be my distribution that I will use to calculate the expected wait time for random arrival to the bus stop

The waiting time can be modeled as *Exponential distribution*, I would also test if the bus arrival process follow a *Poisson distribution* (you have to test with the data, do not just assume it) and as I mentioned above you have to condition your distribution by the time of day and day of week.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :), I agree we would need to do something like that for a bus schedule, but I am only using buses as an example. The real process is fairly regular, and repeats pretty cyclically... Imagine you have n buses that service your stop. The total number of buses is finite, but you don't know the individual periods of those buses, but know that they are regular and cyclic.

Comment: It depend if in your data the bus identifier is included or no. Also, if the person will take the first bus or wait for a specific bus line. But in general the bus arrival process can be modeled as `Posion distribution` if the data *confirms* this i.e.mean and variance are equal

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to work with empirical distributions, i.e., histograms. You can split up the available data according to whatever factors seems important, e.g. weekday vs weekend in the bus example. By the way, note that if the arrival times are approximately cyclic, as you mention, the waiting time will depend on when you start waiting.

You might find, after building histograms and looking at them, that you can simplify things by assuming some specific distribution. But you have to work with the empirical data first to figure out if that's possible.